# Is there any benefit in using std::forward instead of std::move to initialize an object?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a function template that takes an argument of some callable type, and uses `std::bind` to make a new callable object with predefined argument values for the original callable.  I've written it with a forwarding reference parameter and `std::forward`, like this:

```
template <typename F>
auto make_example_caller(F &&f) {
  return std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), 123, 456, 789);
}
```

The [cppreference documentation for `std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) says that the bound object "holds a member object of type `std::decay<F>::type` constructed from `std::forward<F>(f)`".  Since `std::bind` forwards the function to its internal data member, forwarding the same function to the `std::bind` call in my own code seems reasonable and appropriate.

However, it's not clear what benefit that brings.  If `F` is a reference type, `std::decay` removes the reference, so the bind object is going to store its own instance of the callable type.  That instance will be constructed as a move if `F` is an rvalue reference, or a copy if `F` is an lvalue, and I can get the same result if I write my function like this:

```
template <typename F>
auto make_example_caller(F f) {  // Note, no &&
  return std::bind(std::move(f), 123, 456, 789);  // move, not forward
}
```

Now my function's own `f` parameter will be initialized by either move or copy depending on how the function is called, but either way I now have my own instance of the function object, which I can move into the bind object.

The latter way seems simpler, but I wonder if I'm missing something — especially since the same reasoning would apply to `std::bind` itself, yet it takes an `F&&` and forwards it, instead of taking an `F` by value and moving it.  Is there a disadvantage in doing it that way?  Something that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advantages of using forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a forwarding reference and `std::forward` you can eliminate the creation of an extra object.

If you don't use a forwarding reference, you have three objects involved:

1. Caller's original object
2. Function parameter `f`, constructed using the copy or move constructor as appropriate
3. Bind object's internal object, constructed by move constructor

If you use a forwarding reference with `std::forward`, you eliminate the second one.  There will only be two objects created:

1. Caller's original object
2. Bind object's internal object, constructed using the copy or move constructor as appropriate

While move-constructing an object *may* be cheaper than copy-constructing (depending on the type), it still contributes some overhead that perfect-forwarding can avoid.

Comment: Item #3 in your first list is constructed by move constructor, not copy constructor — but I see your point.  I tend to think of the cost of a move constructor as being negligible, but that's not necessarily true in general (though it is in my current situation).

Comment: Oops, you are correct; I misstyped.  Fixed.  I would argue that move-construction is more expensive than perfect-forwarding for any type larger than a pointer.  The actual performance difference may be unmeasurably small in many cases though.  If your type is already a template parameter there's no real reason not to forward, but if its a concrete type (like `std::string`) I agree the extra complexity probably isn't worth it.

Comment: IMO this answer has not enough context to understood it. I think votes are form people who already knew the answer (or they think they do). A live example could be very helpful.

Comment: I don't see how this answers title question "Is `std::forward` > `std::move` in my case?". `std::move` may yield perfect forwarding behaviour in many cases as well, it is not restricted to `std::forward`.

Comment: @R2RT A question is more than its title.  The body of the question makes it pretty clear that the OP is asking about the difference between `std::move`ing a value and `std::forward`ing a forwarding reference.  Furthermore `std::move` will never yield perfect forwarding.  `std::move` will _always_ cast its parameter to an rvalue; it is not value-category preserving like `std::forward`.